# Square and round Brackets for citation

Tags: biblatex

I’m wondering how could I cite mi internet sources with round brackets and my other sources with square brackets. I want to replace the [] of the Wikipedia cite for ().

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,paper=portrait,pagesize=auto,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{Literatur}

\begin{document}
\parencite{Wikipedia.8.05.2017}
\parencite{Yoshizawa.1990}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=Literaturverzeichnis}, nottype=misc]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Internetverzeichnis}, type=misc]
\end{document}
```

Content of `Literature.bib`:

```
@misc{Wikipedia.8.05.2017,
  author = {Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Massenspektrometrie},
  url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massenspektrometrie#Arten_von_Analysatoren},
urldate = {29.05.2017} }


@article{Yoshizawa.1990,
  author = {Yoshizawa, Shigeru and Matsushima, Rie and Watanabe, Mariyo F. and Harada, Ken-ichi and Ichihara, Akira and Carmichael, Wayne W. and Fujiki, Hirota},
  year = {1990},
  title = {Inhibition of protein phosphatases by microcystis and nodularin associated with hepatotoxicity},
  pages = {609--614},
  volume = {116},
 number = {6},
  issn = {0171-5216},
  journal = {Journal of Cancer Research and Clinical Oncology},
  doi = {10.1007/BF01637082},
 }
```

Comment: Does that mean you want to use `\parencite` with square brackets and want to change to round brackets for `@online` entries? What should happen if you cite two sources in the same `\parencite` - a `@book` and an `@online`, say? Do I get square or round brackets? BTW: Please have a look at how to write a  [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Your MWE runs, but it contains many unneeded packages. Your example also includes no `.bib` file and example entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can't use the redefinitions you currently use, since we must be able to use round brackets.

Instead put

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenparen}{\bibopenbracket}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibcloseparen}{\bibclosebracket}}
```

into your preamble.

This uses round brackets for `@online` and square brackets for all other types. (You should use `@online` instead of `@misc` for online entries, if you *must* use `@misc`, replace `\ifentrytype{online}` by `\ifentrytype{misc}`).

Note that this will not give good output for `\parencite{foo,bar}`. But it is unclear what you would want in that case.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenparen}{\bibopenbracket}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibcloseparen}{\bibclosebracket}}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sigfridsson} and \parencite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> [Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998] and (CTAN 2006)

in the citations.